# Dropping Duplicate Points

Tags: pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have two `geodataframes` or `geoseries`, both consists of thousands of `points`.

My requirement is to append (merge) both `geodataframes` and drop duplicate points.

In other words, `output = gdf1 all points + gdf2 points that do not intersect with gdf1 points`

I tried as:

```
output = geopandas.overlay(gdf1, gdf2, how='symmetric_difference')
```

However, it is very slow.

Do you know any faster way of doing it ?

Comment: How many thousands of points? And how slow is very slow? Have you tried using %timeit?

Comment: I'm not able to get results for 5 hours yet...it has 5429812 points in gdf1 and 6498712 points  in gdf2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way of combining dataframes using pandas, along with timings, versus geopandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=10000)
data2 = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=10000)

df1 = pd.concat([-pd.Series(data1, name="longitude"), pd.Series(data1, name="latitude")], axis=1)
df1['geometry'] = df1.apply(lambda x: (x['latitude'], x['longitude']), axis=1)

df2 = pd.concat([-pd.Series(data2, name="longitude"), pd.Series(data2, name="latitude")], axis=1)
df2['geometry'] = df2.apply(lambda x: (x['latitude'], x['longitude']), axis=1)

df1 = df1.set_index(["longitude", "latitude"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["longitude", "latitude"])

%timeit pd.concat([df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)],df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]])
    
112 ms ± 217 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This seems a lot faster than using geopandas

```
import geopandas as gp

gdf1 = gp.GeoDataFrame(
    df1, geometry=gp.points_from_xy(df1.index.get_level_values("longitude"), df1.index.get_level_values("latitude")))
gdf2 = gp.GeoDataFrame(
    df2, geometry=gp.points_from_xy(df2.index.get_level_values("longitude"), df2.index.get_level_values("latitude")))

%timeit gp.overlay(gdf1, gdf2, how='symmetric_difference')

29 s ± 317 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But maybe you need some kind of optimisations as mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175228/geopandas-spatial-join-extremely-slow).

The function checks for non-matching indexes from each df and then combines them.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4],columns=['col1']).set_index("col1")
df2 = pd.DataFrame([3,4,5,6],columns=['col1']).set_index("col1")
pd.concat([df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)],df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]])

col1
1
2
5
6
```

Comment: Is `df1.combine_first(df2)` dropping the duplicate points ?

Comment: Sorry, no I got that wrong. You want to get non-matching indexes from each df and then combine them. I've shown how you can do this.